# Oracle cannot get sqlldr to reach listener, get ORA-12514 error

Tags: oracle, sql-loader, tnsnames

Every time I try to run the following sqlldr command on a terminal only oracle 19c system:

```
sqlldr username/password@$HOSTNAME/$ORACLE_SID control=rules.ctl log=backup_error_logs.txt data=output.csv errors=1000000
```

I get the following error message:

```
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
```

Things I have tried:

Verified that the listener is operable and listener.ora file is properly formatted with lsnrctl.

Verified the connection and oracle environment variables are working as the following sqlplus command runs without problem:

```
sqlplus username/password@$HOSTNAME/$ORACLE_SID
```

Verified the tnsname.ora is running properly configured with the following tnsping command:

```
tnsping $ORACLE_SID
```

Cannot think of anything else to try or to check. Does anyone have any advice without resorting to the GUI tools?

Comment: `tnsping $ORACLE_SID` is using an alias defined in your `tnsnames.ora`; connecting with `@$HOSTNAME/$ORACLE_SID` is not using that file, it is connecting directly to a service with that name registered to a listener on default port 1521 on whatever `$HOSTNAME` evaluates to. So... are you sure the successful SQL\*Plus connection includes the `$HOSTNAME/` part and isn't just `@$ORACLE_SID`? And if not, how is the alias defined in your `tnsnames.ora`?

Comment: Basically it's defined as below, but with anything with a $ in it written out:

    $ORACLE_SID = 
    (DESCRIPTION = 
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP) (HOST = $HOSTNAME)(PORT = 1521))
      (CONNECT_DATA = 
            (SID=$ORACLE_SID)
            (SERVER = DEDICATED)     
           (SERVICE_NAME = $ORACLE_SID)
      ) 
)

Comment: tnsping only validates that the listener is turned on. *It does not validate the SID or service_name*. Also note that ORACLE_SID and SERVICE_NAME are *not* the same thing, and not necessarily interchangeable, depending on your configuration.

Comment: Just tried sqlplus username/password@$HOSTNAME.

Gave a ORA-12504: error in that TNS:Listener cannot resolve SERVICE_NAME, which is the same as the ORACLE_SID.

SHOW PARAMETER SERVICE_NAME query on the database. The ORACLE_SID and SERVICE_NAME came out to the same value.

Comment: Problem solved. The $HOSTNAME variable was not resolving the FQDN. Once this was found the sqlldr runs just fine.

Thank you for the advice, Alex Poole and pmdba. You really were a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a problem of quotes in the variables, the behavior of both tools is different regarding quotes.

Comment: I did just check each of the environment variables, listener.ora, tnsnames.ora, and the command structure. Quotes aren't used, so I don't believe that's the problem.